# Python - Multiple inheritance with multiple __init__()s?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

So I've dabbled with Python, and have generally heard it's good form to write `__init__()`s for your classes. Python also supports multiple inheritance. However, I've run into an issue where I'm trying to have 2 unrelated classes, both with `__init__()`s, and I want to make a subclass of those both. For example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, randparam):
        self.randparam = randparam
        
    def func(self):
        return 2 * self.randparam

class B():
    def __init__(self, paramrand):
        self.paramrand = paramrand

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init___()
        super().__init___() 
        #this won't result in both of the __init__()s running, obviously...
```

Here, I'm trying to make sure class C has both the attributes `randparam` and `paramrand`, in addition to the method `func()`. How can I achieve this? Is this even doable in Python, or do I have to account for such issues in advance by making class B a subclass of class A? Or how else can I make sure both `__init__()`s for both classes run when I use them both as base classes in a similar case to the code example above?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but if you are going to use cooperative multiple inheritance, then all your classes need to use `super()`.

Comment: Give this a read: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance